# Vue.js prefetch CSS files

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, lighthouse

I have a Vue CLI 3 project, with lazy loading for the components. When running `npm run build` and serving the `dist` folder, I see that a CSS file is first prefetched and then loaded:

`<link href="/css/article.70090a14.css" rel="prefetch">`
and
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/article.70090a14.css">`

This is the default behaviour of the Webpack config when executing `npm run build`. At the moment Lighthouse (Google's audit tool) is complaining and advises me the following:

"Preload key requests: `/css/article.70090a14.css`"

My question is, how can I add to / change this behaviour to do a `preload` instead of a `prefetch`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to prefetch css files:
https://github.com/MarvelSQ/html-prefetch-css-webpack-plugin

or

you can use [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) to integrate css into js file and then prefetch js file using `webpackPrefetch` magic comment:

```
import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ "...")
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this without yet another dependency? Aren't there Vue specific tools available that I am missing atm?

Comment: As webpack builds your statics I don't think that Vue has anything to say here.

Comment: But you may want to read this: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html